# Gradient UIButton's border with corner radius

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uibutton, gradient

I wrote the code, which works on iPhone X, but doesn't work on iPhone SE. 
[Here's what we have on iPhone SE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wMjEx.png)

Have someone any ideas why it works on iPhone X correctly and doesn't on iPhone SE

I call this function in viewDidLayoutSubviews()

```
extension UIView {
    enum Direction {
        case horizontal
        case vertical
    }

    func addGradient(cornerRadius: CGFloat, colors: [UIColor], lineWidth: CGFloat, direction: Direction) {
       self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = bounds
        gradient.colors = colors.map({ (color) -> CGColor in
            color.cgColor
        })

        switch direction {
        case .horizontal:
            gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
            gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
        case .vertical:
            gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        }

        var shadowLayer: CAShapeLayer!
        shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shadowLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shadowLayer.path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds.insetBy(dx: lineWidth, dy: lineWidth), cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
        shadowLayer.fillColor = nil
        shadowLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        gradient.mask = shadowLayer
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }
}
```

Comment: When do you call that `addGradient` function?

Comment: @AndréSlotta in viewDidLayoutSubviews()

Comment: Can you show that `viewDidLayoutSubviews` code?

Comment: So I guess that `addGradient()` is called twice. It's done in the correct method (after the layout have been done), but you should remove the layer if there was one before to avoid your double issue (or fix another issue that make it be called twice).

Comment: @AndréSlotta  serversButtonOutlet.addGradient(cornerRadius: 31.0, colors:  [UIColor(red: 49/256, green: 211/256, blue: 179/256, alpha: 1.0), UIColor(red: 68/256, green: 164/256, blue: 214/256, alpha: 1.0)], lineWidth: 2.0, direction: .horizontal)

Comment: @Larme we added check code (see the answer down below) but it doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

Since `viewDidLayoutSubviews` gets called multiple times you have to make sure that you create the gradient layer only once. Add a check like this:

```
func addGradient(cornerRadius: CGFloat, colors: [UIColor], lineWidth: CGFloat, direction: Direction) {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius

    if let gradient = self.layer.sublayers?.last as? CAGradientLayer {
        // gradient layer already exists - update its frame
        gradient.frame = bounds
    } else {
        // gradient layer does not exist yet - create it
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = bounds
        gradient.colors = colors.map({ (color) -> CGColor in
            color.cgColor
        })

        switch direction {
        case .horizontal:
            gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
            gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
        case .vertical:
            gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
            gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
        }

        var shadowLayer: CAShapeLayer!
        shadowLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        let rectPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds.insetBy(dx: lineWidth, dy: lineWidth), cornerRadius: cornerRadius).cgPath
        shadowLayer.path = rectPath
        shadowLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shadowLayer.fillColor = nil
        shadowLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        gradient.mask = shadowLayer
        self.layer.addSublayer(gradient)
    }
}
```